# #1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'course'

Tags: mysql

I am trying to join four tables using the below query and I get the above error

```
SELECT student.names, student.surname,
   coursemarks.mark,
   class.form,class.id
FROM `student`, `course`
INNER JOIN `course` on course.courseid = coursemarks.course.id
INNER JOIN `coursemarks` on student.idNumber = coursemarks.studentid
INNER JOIN `class`on student.idNumber = class.studentID;
```

Here is my database schema is like i have a student table with a primary key idNumber. the coursemarks is linked to the student by referrencing the student.idNumber key. the coursemarks table is linked to the course  table by referrencing the courseID key in the course field. The class table also references the student.idNumber key. How do i solve this problem

Comment: `FROM course` is not needed as it is `inner joined`.

Comment: `FROM student, course` statement cross-joins tables `student` and `course`. After that you have `INNER JOIN course...` and MySQL interprets that as another JOIN, but this time `course` is used twice - hence non unique alias course.

Comment: if i do that it gives the error "#1054 - Unknown column 'coursemarks.course.id' in 'on clause' "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your Query. You are trying to use Course table multiple times one as below and another when you join. Remove , `course` from below line:

```
FROM `student`, `course`
```

So it looks like

```
FROM `student`
```

Also change the order of join statement (one with course and coursemarks) as below

```
SELECT student.names, student.surname,
   coursemarks.mark,
   class.form,class.id
FROM `student`
INNER JOIN `coursemarks` on student.idNumber = coursemarks.studentid
INNER JOIN `course` on course.courseid = coursemarks.courseid
INNER JOIN `class`on student.idNumber = class.studentID;
```

Comment: it gives me the error "#1054 - Unknown column 'coursemarks.course.id' in 'on clause' "

Comment: do you have any idea on how i can create a prepared statement in java on this query

Comment: Please raise this as a new question. See [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/preparestatement-object-example.htm) example.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT s.names
     , s.surname
     , m.mark
     , l.form
     , l.id
  FROM student s
  JOIN coursemarks m 
    ON m.studentid =  s.idNumber
  JOIN course c 
    ON c.courseid = m.course.id
  JOIN class l 
    ON s.idNumber = l.studentID;
```